# How can we unserialize WordPress complex nested objects string retrieve from Database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know how we can unserialize the long and nested string which retrieve from WordPress table.
Example string is bellow.

```
 "a:2:{s:12:\"package_hash\";s:40:\"wc_ship_6edf782f440b0f0efece7fc5bc6e4289\";s:5:\"rates\";a:2:{s:15:\"free_shipping:5\";O:16:\"WC_Shipping_Rate\":2:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000data\";a:6:{s:2:\"id\";s:15:\"free_shipping:5\";s:9:\"method_id\";s:13:\"free_shipping\";s:11:\"instance_id\";i:5;s:5:\"label\";s:13:\"Free shipping\";s:4:\"cost\";s:4:\"0.00\";s:5:\"taxes\";a:0:{}}s:12:\"\u0000*\u0000meta_data\";a:1:{s:5:\"Items\";s:147:\"About Time - Vegan Protein Power - Vanilla - 2 Lbs. &times; 1, Green Foods True Vitality Plant Protein Shake With Dha Chocolate - 25.2 Oz &times; 7\";}}s:15:\"ShipEngine_usps\";O:16:\"WC_Shipping_Rate\":2:{s:7:\"\u0000*\u0000data\";a:6:{s:2:\"id\";s:15:\"ShipEngine_usps\";s:9:\"method_id\";s:15:\"ShipEngine_usps\";s:11:\"instance_id\";i:0;s:5:\"label\";s:13:\"USPS Shipping\";s:4:\"cost\";s:5:\"16.00\";s:5:\"taxes\";a:0:{}}s:12:\"\u0000*\u0000meta_data\";a:0:{}}}}"
```

After using unserialize php function it is skipping nested rates data

```
   "package_hash":"wc_ship_6edf782f440b0f0efece7fc5bc6e4289",
   "rates":{
      "free_shipping:5":{
         
      },
      "ShipEngine_usps":{
         
      }
   }
}
```

Please help if any one know something.

Comment: Did you try native wordpress function?https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/

Comment: Yes i tried same result.